# Sharing current page screenshot

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

I am developing app for windows phone 8.1, in two functionality are there, user can share **Text** and **current page screenshot** to another app currently text sharing functionality working. 
I'd like to implement share current page screenshot.
How to do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to programmatically take a screenshot on windows phone?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20280120/how-to-programmatically-take-a-screenshot-on-windows-phone)

Comment: Thanks Its working. it take screenshot only device view area.

Comment: I want to capture complete control data. In grid I have taken listview in listview there 50 records I want to capture screenshots of all records. Is it possible, if it is possible how to do this?