# How can I take a screenshot programmatically in Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, screenshot

I'm little bit confusing with taking screenshot of the current window programmatically and save it in the phone's gallery.
There are no any tutorials for Windows Phone 8.1.

```
private async Task<RenderTargetBitmap>CreateBitmapFromElement(FrameworkElement uielement)try{
    var renderTargetBitmap = new RenderTargetBitmap();
    await renderTargetBitmap.RenderAsync(uielement);

    return renderTargetBitmap;
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex);
}
return null;}
```

I have this code. How can I save this to the media library?

Comment: I'm marking is as a duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20280120/how-to-programmatically-take-a-screenshot-on-window).

Anyway, Microsoft Virtual Academy offers a good deal of tutorials about Windows Phone 8.1 development. Take a look [here](https://mva.microsoft.com/en-us/training-courses/windows-phone-8-1-development-for-absolute-beginners-8375?l=7j1Mg9Hz_8804984382)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to programmatically take a screenshot on windows phone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20280120/how-to-programmatically-take-a-screenshot-on-windows-phone)

Answer (score -2):

Press the power button & the volume button together at the same time.

Comment: Don't know of any way to do this programmatically. You could save an image that is in the foreground of your app, but not the entire screen.